# How to write MySql query with two left joins and two counts

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have three tables posts,comments,likes and I want to fetch all posts with their amount of likes and comments I've tried this

```
SELECT posts.id,COUNT(comments.postId) as num_of_comments,COUNT(likes.postId) as num_of_likes                                                                     
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.postId = posts.id
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.postId = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the left join for on the subquery with group by result

```
select  posts.id, t1.num_of_comments, t2.num_of_likes
from posts
leftjoin (
  select comments.postId, COUNT(*) as num_of_comments
  from comments 
  group by comments.postId
) t1 on t1.postId = posts.id
leftjoin (
  select likes.postId, COUNT(*) as num_of_likes
  from likes
  group by likes.postId
) t2 on t2.postId = posts.id
```